# If an Application Password is accidentally revoked, is there any way to restore it?

Tags: database, rest-api, password

The concern is that it is too easy for the internal webmaster or admin to
accidentally revoke an application password for an application name for a
specific user.

In this case the application password is hardcoded into a desktop application.
This application incorporates a hardcoded Wordpress URL for POST uploads, a
generic Wordpress username (eg "telemetry") and an Application Password (not
login password).  This application is distributed externally, so once it leaves
the shop it will be hard to update.

Where or how is the Application Password stored in the DB?  Must be a simple
matter to simply restore that information if necesary.

Comment: keep in mind that if you need to revoke that application password for security reasons then this situation will be very very bad for you, if you're using this for telemetry is it necessary to lock it behind authenticated REST API endpoints with hardcoded permanent application passwords?